# how to restore escreen configuration on emacs startup?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Is there a way to restore all escreen screens and window configurations on emacs startup?

I tried to add the (escreen-configuration-alist) to desktop-saved-globals with no result.

I also tried to execute some code manually, but whenever I run (escreen-restore-screen-map screen-map) with screen-map being export of current escreen screen map, I get "wrong argument type window-configuration-p".

Not an elisp expert and a little bit stuck.

If there's no luck with escreen, maybe el-screen has the needed functionality?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, escreen use the window configuration as defined in Emacs. Unfortunately window configuration is hard coded in C and there is no serialization. So you cannot save/restore between sessions but simply register it.
The only way is to rewrite window configuration in Emacs Lisp. HIROSE Yuuji wrote his own window configuration and it works great! I enhanced it to support frames and escreen case and post it on github: https://github.com/martialboniou/revive-plus
I provided this package WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY. No unit test, for instance, but it should work. Let me know (it's a fresh hack so there will be refactoring soon)!